# Array map with regular expression

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array as below:

```
arr = [
  nil,
  6,
  "17 to 23 ||'.'||24 to 25 (add a decimal at 10th place)",
  nil,
  nil,
  "37 to 51 ||'.'||52 to 53 (add a decimal at 100th place)",
  nil
]
```

I want to convert this array into the following:

```
arr = [
  nil,
  6,
  "10th",
  nil,
  nil,
  "100th",
  nil
]
```

i.e from the string `"17 to 23 ||'.'||24 to 25 (add a decimal at 10th place)"`, I need the digits mentioned in the bracket.

I tried the following code, but its not working:

```
arr.map! {|e| e[/^.*?add.*?(\d+)th.*?$/]}
```

Comment: Do you only have to match `...th`? What about `...2nd` and `...3rd`?

Comment: i want to match `th` only

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code fails because `obj[pattern]` only works for strings and not for `nil` or integers (there is [`Integer#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Integer.html#method-i-5B-5D) but it does something else):

```
nil[/foo/] #=> NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
123[/foo/] #=> TypeError: no implicit conversion of Regexp into Integer
```

You could use `=~` instead which is defined on [`Object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Object.html#method-i-3D-7E) and overridden by subclasses, e.g. [`String`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-3D-7E):

```
arr.map {|e| e =~ /(\d+th)/ ? $1 : e }
#=> [nil, 6, "10th", nil, nil, "100th", nil]
```

If `e` matches `/(\d+th)/`, return [`$1`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Special+global+variables) (the first capture group), otherwise `e` itself.

You can also use a more specific pattern:

```
/add a decimal at (\d+th) place/
```